# Echarts: How to display last label of xAxis?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

How to show the last tick label of xAxis?

Screenshot: [chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5joac.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following configuration option:

```
xAxis: {
  axisLabel: { showMaxLabel: true },
  ...
}
```